# AngularJS - DRY (input fields, function, directive)

Tags: angularjs

I am fairly new to AngularJS and I got in situation where my code starts to repeat. I am thinking of creating a new directive but for now I am a bit confused with scope/isolated scope/directive's controller/etc. issues.

Here is what I am trying to achieve. Please have in mind that my code is already working but without directive, so I will put this in a very theoretic way.

I have two inputs, one for city and one for zip code.

```
<input get-zip name="city" ng-model="city" ng-blur="getZip();" />
<input name="zip" ng-model="zip" />
```

When user enters city and leaves input field, a function getZip() should be called (passing param: value of city input) which then searches corresponded zip code and enters it into zip field.

In some situations we could have two city-zip inputs on the same form. In this case we need to pass zip input name or model into calling function, so we can then append zip value to the right input.

What would be the right way to solve this issue? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the zip and city inputs as directives inside a directive. You can then have many of these pairs each with their own scope.

The directive containing these elements:

```
(function () {

    angular.module('myApp.directives').directive('cityZipInputPair', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: '/Templates/Directives/CityZipInputPair.html',
            scope: {
                city: '=',
                zip: '='
            },
            controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
                $scope.getZip = function(){
                    // handle functionality here with $scope.zip and $scope.city
                }

            }]
        }
    });
}).call(this);
```

CityZipInputPair.html should then look like:

```
<input get-zip name="city" ng-model="city" ng-blur="getZip();" />
<input name="zip" ng-model="zip" />
```

The directive can then be put onto the page multiple times as follows:

```
<city-zip-input-pair city="city1" zip="zip1"></city-zip-input-pair>
<city-zip-input-pair city="city2" zip="zip2"></city-zip-input-pair>
```

Comment: Why are we using scope three times? a) scope: {} b) $scope c) function($scope)

Comment: a) scope: {} 
Defines an isolated scope for the directive. You can have three different types of scope in a directive. Within this isolated scope you are defining two way bindings with the '='. 
b and c) you are injecting $scope into the controller so that it can be used in the controller. This is the same as your would inject other services such as $http into a controller. 
The reason you need b) is to make it min-safe.

Comment: I understand point **a**. So, for the point **c**, we are injecting isolated scope under point **a**, right? I have tried not defining point **b** and directive also works, maybe just in my case? @Sam, thank you for trying to (further) explain it to me.

Comment: For point c we are injecting the angular $scope service which includes all that two way binding magic etc. It just happens that you have defined some variables in this $scope service in point a. 
Yes, point b is not required if you are not minifying your javascript. However, if you do minify it to make it run faster in a production system, then $scope will be renamed to something like 'a' and the injection will no longer work. Thus, the need for point b.